# Left Join using Linq with condition

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I am trying to create a left join with a condition in my C# code. I can write it in SQL Server, but I am having problems writing it as a lambda expression. Here is a rough part of my SQL Code:

```
Select x.RequestId, aud.DepartmentId
From Requests x
Left Join UserDepartment ud on x.AssignedToTeam = ud.DepartmentId and ud.User = 'Joe'
```

I know how to write the Left Join but am unfamiliar with how or if it is possible to add the condition.

Comment: What's `aud`? You've declared `ud` - should *that* be `aud`?

Comment: You might want to go through and accept some answers, also

Answer (score 3):

I *suspect* you want something like this:

```
var query = from request in db.Requests
            join department in db.UserDepartments
                                 .Where(dep => dep.User == "Joe")
              on request.AssignedToTeam equals department.DepartmentId
              into departments
            from dep in departments.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { request.RequestId,
                         DepartmentId = dep == null ? null : (int?) dep.DepartmentId
            };
```

(Obviously change how you want to handle the absence of a department ID if necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MSDN article: [How to: Perform Left Outer Joins (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
var request = db.View.Join(
    db.UserDepartment.Where(w=>w.User=="Joe"),
    a=>a.AssignedToTeam, 
    b=>b.DepartmentId, 
    (a,b)=> new {View = a, UserDepartment = b});
```